# Would this be ok to control the speed of a PC fan?

Tags: mains, 12v, dimmer

I have a 240mm PC fan connected to a 12v adapter. The fan is quite noisy and i would like to have the option to turn the speed up/down or off completely.

The Fan is: Current (A): 0.18
The 12v Mains adapter is: Output 12v 1a

I've seen this LED Light Dimmer switch on amazon and other sites, Just wondering would it work in the same way as just giving the fan less volts and therefore slowing it down ?

However the dimmer is 8a output, Would it be safe?

[image]

Comment: With regard to current usage, you might want to read through [Olin's excellent question and answer about power supplies](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/2028). It will help you understand the relationship between the current ratings of the fan (load) and the supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimmer will work fine, just remember to don't exceed the 800mA maximum *load* current. If the PSU has a big amperage that's not a problem, but if you connect to many fans in parallel (yes you can do that!) then you might exceed the rating and fry the dimmer.

go for it!

Comment: The PSU is only 1a, is it ok that the dimmer is more amp?

Comment: The dimmer seems to be .8A to me, that is 800mA, that is less than 1A. In any case that won't be a problem either, actually it would be better since breaking the dimmer would be impossible...

Comment: Hmm, here is the link to it, Hope its ok to link to this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/12V-14V-Dimmer-Switch-Brightness-Controller/dp/B008TNH68E/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1398792408&sr=8-7&keywords=led+dimmer

Comment: That's 8A, as you said, so you'll just need not to exceed your psu max current

Comment: Ok, well i only plan to add 1 fan, possibly 3 at max if i need too. so i assume that will be safe. On my fan there is 3 black wires, I'm guessing the white strip means positive but how do i know which of the 2 black ones are negative? https://www.dropbox.com/s/u93avjnitzgjp89/2014-04-29%2018.47.16.jpg